# Vertex Colors in THREE.Line

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm trying to draw a line in Three.js with different colors for different vertices, using `THREE.Line` and `THREE.LineBasicMaterial`, with `vertexColors` set to `THREE.VertexColors`. I would prefer that there is no interpolation between the colors of adjacent vertices (such that the color just changes discontinuously at the halfway point between two vertices).

I tried setting `shading: THREE.FlatShading` on the material, but I realize now that that's not an option for `LineBasicMaterial`: http://jsfiddle.net/214huf0a/

Is there a built-in (or easy) way to prevent smoothing of color between points on a line in Three.js, or do I need to write my own shader?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a line in three.js having one color on each segment by using the `THREE.LineSegments` and setting `vertexColors = THREE.VertexColors`;

```
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i+=2 ) {
    geometry.colors[ i ] = new THREE.Color( Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() );
    geometry.colors[ i + 1 ] = geometry.colors[ i ];
}

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
} );

var line = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry, material );
```

three.js r.85

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Our of curiosity, is the different behavior with `THREE.LinePieces` a consequence of the particular shaders that Three.js uses to render `LineBasicMaterial`, or the fact that setting the mode to `THREE.LinePieces` triggers a draw call with `GL_LINES` rather than `GL_LINE_STRIP`?